# PyTorch: access weights of a specific module in nn.Sequential()

Tags: python, pytorch

When I use a pre-defined module in PyTorch, I can typically access its weights fairly easily. However, how do I access them if I wrapped the module in `nn.Sequential()` first? r.g:

```
class My_Model_1(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,D_in,D_out):
        super(My_Model_1, self).__init__()
        self.layer = nn.Linear(D_in,D_out)
    def forward(self,x):
        out = self.layer(x)
        return out

class My_Model_2(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,D_in,D_out):
        super(My_Model_2, self).__init__()
        self.layer = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(D_in,D_out))
    def forward(self,x):
        out = self.layer(x)
        return out

model_1 = My_Model_1(10,10)
print(model_1.layer.weight)
model_2 = My_Model_2(10,10)
```

How do I print the weights now?
`model_2.layer.0.weight` doesn't work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the [PyTorch forum](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/access-weights-of-a-specific-module-in-nn-sequential/3627), this is the recommended way:

```
model_2.layer[0].weight
```

Comment: This method doesn't work anymore. Access to modules iterator is possible using the modules() method.

Comment: This method still works fine for me. It used to break if you wrap your model in DataParallel, and I think it still does. But this was not the original question asked in this thread. (PyTorch 1.5)

Comment: @mbpaulus No it does not

Comment: I don't know what you guys are doing, but this works totally fine in Pytorch 1.6.0. I just tested it once again. I can send you the notebook if you want to.

Answer (score 12):

An easy way to access the weights is to use the `state_dict()` of your model.

This should work in your case:

```
for k, v in model_2.state_dict().iteritems():
    print("Layer {}".format(k))
    print(v)
```

Another option is to get the `modules()` iterator. If you know beforehand the type of your layers this should also work:

```
for layer in model_2.modules():
   if isinstance(layer, nn.Linear):
        print(layer.weight)
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your reply. I also posted in PyTorch Forums and I found the recommended way. I posted an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You can access modules by name using `_modules`:

```py
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()

        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 3, 3)

    def forward(self, input):
        return self.conv1(input)

model = Net()
print(model._modules['conv1'])
```